# Methods with 2 generic types in class with 1 generic type

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public class P1 {
  public P2 P2 { get; set; }
  public P4 P4 { get; set; }
}

public class P2 {
  public P3 P3 { get; set; }
}

public class P3 { }

public class P4 { }
```

I need a Mapper for P1 as follows:

```
Mapper mapper = new Mapper<P1>();
```

But I would like to use it as follows:

```
Mapper<P1> mapper = Mapper.For<P1>()
  .Add(p1 => p1.P2).And(p2 => p2.P3)
  .Add(p1 => p1.P4);
```

So I have:

```
public class Mapper {
  public static Mapper<T> For<T>() {
    return new Mapper<T>();
  }
}

public class Mapper<T> {

  private List<LambdaExpression> _expressions = new List<LambdaExpression>();

  public Mapper<T> Add<K>(Expression<Func<T, K>> expression) {
    // Add expression to expressions
    return this;
  }

  public Mapper<T> And<K>(Expression<Func<T, K>> expression) {
    // Add expression to expressions
    return this;
  }

}
```

My problem is how to deal with Child Properties.

**Note that my Mapper code only allows to do this:**

```
  Mapper<P1> mapper = Mapper.For<P1>()
    .Add(p1 => p1.P2).And(p1 => p1.P2.P3);
```

**And not this:**

```
  Mapper<P1> mapper = Mapper.For<P1>()
    .Add(p1 => p1.P2).And(p2 => p2.P3);
```

I think the methods should return Mapper but in fact I want to create a Mapper ...

K is only a way to define the expression when calling a method.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

**UPDATE**

Answer with ContinuationMapper:

```
public class Mapper<T> {

  protected List<LambdaExpression> Paths { get; set; } = new List<LambdaExpression>();

  public ContinuationMapper<T, TCont> Add<TCont>(Expression<Func<T, TCont>> path) {

    Paths.Add(path);

    return new ContinuationMapper<T, TCont>(Paths);

  }

}

public class ContinuationMapper<TBase, TCurrent> : Mapper<TBase> {

  public ContinuationMapper(List<LambdaExpression> paths) {
    Paths = paths;
  }

  public ContinuationMapper<TBase, TNext> And<TNext>(Expression<Func<TCurrent, TNext>> path) {

    base.Paths.Add(path);

    return new ContinuationMapper<TBase, TNext>(base.Paths);

  }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you need to do that you're hitting a problem with. The code being proposed is allowed. (you can have subgeneric methods in generic classes)

Comment: `Does anyone knows how to do this?`  What is "this"?

Comment: I just added how I can use it at the moment and what I would like to do. Does it help?

Comment: Use 2 generic types not bound to the generic type of the class

Comment: @AlexKrupka not sure what you mean as in the end I need a Mapper<T>. Do I need a new method at the end?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can enforce your mapper to only allow some things and not other ; what prevents me to do `And(p1 => 42);` ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht I am not sure what you mean ... I am kind of trying to replicate Include and ThenInclude approach of Entity Framework: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/78476005b30ff201d4523d24da090ce6c84fb248/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2227 and https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/78476005b30ff201d4523d24da090ce6c84fb248/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2291 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following problems with your current approach:

- It shouldn't be possible to do an `And` before an `Add`.
- At the end of an `And` (or an `Add`), you have *two* types of type information: The *base type* for a new `Add`, and the *continuation type* for a new `And`. You cannot "store" that type of information at compile-time in a generic type with only one generic parameter.

Luckily, the type system can help here, *if* we split your one class in two:

```
public class Mapper<T>
{
    public ContinuationMapper<T, TCont> Add<TCont>(Expression<Func<T, TCont>> expression) {
        // ...
        return new ContinuationMapper<T, TCont>(...);
    }
}

public class ContinuationMapper<TBase, TCurrent> : Mapper<TBase>
{
    public ContinuationMapper<TBase, TNext> And<TNext>(Expression<Func<TCurrent, TNext>> expression) {
        // ...
        return new ContinuationMapper<TBase, TNext>(...);
    }
}
```

Obviously, you will have to pass the state of your expression list to the new classes, which is left as an exercise to the reader. As an added bonus, you can even make your classes immutable, if you want.

Comment: I think that is what I am looking for but I am getting the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ContinuationMapper<TBase, TNext>' to 'ContinuationMapper<TCurrent, TNext>'

Comment: @MiguelMoura: Typo, should be fixed now.

Comment: Could you check my update? I added the code to pass the state to the new classes. Was this what you meant? I am not sure if this is the right way to do it with your code. Thank You

Comment: @MiguelMoura: Looks good to me. An alternative would be to use an ImmutableList, but that depends on whether you want m1 and m2 to be the same or different in the following example: `var m1 = Mapper.For<P1>().Add(p1 => p1.P2); var m2 = m1.And(p2 => p2.P3);`. In your code, both m1 and m2 contain a reference to the same list of lambda expressions. If you use an immutable list and pass `list.Add` to the constructor of the next mapper, `m1` will contain only one lambda and `m2` both.

Answer (score 0):

In essence you don't want to bind the method types to the class type so you need to use 2 new generic types. sort of like the following.

```
 public Mapper<T> Add<V,K>(Expression<Func<V, K>> expression) {
    // Add expression to expressions
    return this;
  }

  public Mapper<T> And<V,K>(Expression<Func<V, K>> expression) {
    // Add expression to expressions
    return this;
  }
```

Example:

```
Mapper<P1> mapper = Mapper.For<P1>()
 .Add((P1 p1) => p1.P2).And((P2 p2) => p2.P3)
 .Add((P1 p1) => p1.P4);
```

If you want the `Add` to be tied to the `T` and the and to be tied to the last property you'll need to provide back a wrapper class like

```
Mapper<T,V>{
public Mapper<T> Add<V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> expression) {
// Add expression to expressions
return Mapper.Wrap<T,V>(this);
}

public Mapper<T> And<V>(Expression<Func<V, K>> expression) {
    // Add expression to expressions
 return this;
   }
 }
```

Comment: But when I try to use your code I get The type arguments for method 'Mapper<P1>.Add<V, K>(Expression<Func<V, K>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. Can you provide an example of how are you using it?

Comment: Just provided an example